Join 2 tables, many-to-many, but show unique elements from both tables
I hope I can explain the result I want to achieve.
I have two tables, and I want to join these 2 tables, but the union of both shows me unique results. I don't know if the relationship is wrong and there is a better way to edit these tables on the server.
Example - Table A:



IdUser
IdProject
IdTool
Status




1
a
1
yes


1
a
15
yes


1
a
31
no



Table B:



IdUser
IdProject
IdTool
IdEval
Status




1
a
31
1
no


1
a
31
2
no


1
a
31
3
yes



I have tried to get this result but it has been very complicated for me
Desired result:



IdUser
IdProject
IdTool
IdEval
StatusA
StatusB




1
a
1
null
yes
null


1
a
15
null
yes
null


1
a
31
null
no
null


1
a
31
1
null
no


1
a
31
2
null
no


1
a
31
3
null
yes



I hope you can help me and I thank you from the bottom of my heart in advance.
UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that in Table A I have 592,000 records and in Table B I only have these 3 records, and I would like you to show me the result of the records that contain only information from Table B including their information from Table A without a WHERE, I don't know if it is possible and I am racking my brain for something that cannot be done with simple JOIN, I tried with LEFT JOIN, INTERSECT, and with GROUP but I was not able to obtain the desired result. I hope I have been clear and excuse my English. Greetings

You actually seem to want a union of the two tables, rather than some kind of join:
SELECT IdUser, IdProject, IdTool, IdEval, NULL AS StatusA, Status AS StatusB
FROM TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT IdUser, IdProject, IdTool, IdEval, Status, NULL
FROM TableA
ORDER BY IdUser, IdProject, IdTool;


Thank you very much, I tried what you suggested but I get all the information from Table A, something I forgot to mention. Let me explain, in Table A I have 592,000 records and in B I only have these 3 records, and I would like to show the result of the records that contain only information from Table B including the information from Table A, this without a WHERE, I don't know if it is possible and I am racking my brain for something that cannot be done with simple JOINs. I hope I have been clear.

You should have provided sample data which makes it clear what you want.

Unfortunately your ask is not very clear, let me share two versions that might help you - 
Solution 1) 
SELECT 
    b.IdUser, 
    b.IdProject, 
    b.IdTool, 
    b.IdEval, 
    a.Status AS StatusA, 
    b.Status AS StatusB 
FROM 
    TableA a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TableB b 
ON 
    a.IdUser = b.IdUser 
    AND a.IdProject = b.IdProject 
    AND a.IdTool = b.IdTool;


Solution 2) 
-- Step 1: Include all records from Table A with potential matches from Table B
SELECT 
    a.IdUser, 
    a.IdProject, 
    a.IdTool, 
    NULL AS IdEval, 
    a.Status AS StatusA, 
    NULL AS StatusB
FROM 
    TableA a
LEFT JOIN 
    TableB b 
ON 
    a.IdUser = b.IdUser 
    AND a.IdProject = b.IdProject 
    AND a.IdTool = b.IdTool
WHERE 
    b.IdEval IS NULL  -- Only include records where Table B doesn't have a match

UNION ALL

-- Step 2: Include all records from Table B with potential matches from Table A
SELECT 
    b.IdUser, 
    b.IdProject, 
    b.IdTool, 
    b.IdEval, 
    a.Status AS StatusA, 
    b.Status AS StatusB
FROM 
    TableB b
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TableA a 
ON 
    a.IdUser = b.IdUser 
    AND a.IdProject = b.IdProject 
    AND a.IdTool = b.IdTool;


@pedro if you would post the SQL query that you are using that would be more useful in finding out what are you trying to do and where the issue is. But given the details, the following query would work for your case - 
SELECT IdUser, IdProject, IdTool, NULL as IdEval, Status as StatusA, NULL as StatusB
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT IdUser, IdProject, IdTool, IdEval, NULL as StatusA, Status as StatusB
FROM TableB;


Thank you very much rise.ashok , I have tried with Join, Left Join and Intersect without satisfactory results. I apologize, I forgot to mention that in Table A I have 592,000 records and in B I only have these 3 records, and I would like to show the result of the records that contain only information from Table B including their information from Table A, this without a WHERE. I hope I have been clear. Greetings

@PedroSegura Thanks for the clarification, this helps. If I get your question right, what you asked for can be solved with simple left join -
You ask is show the records that contain only information from Table B including their information from Table A without a WHERE clause so try this SQL -
SELECT
b.IdUser,
b.IdProject,
b.IdTool,
b.IdEval,
a.Status AS StatusA,
b.Status AS StatusB
FROM TableB b
LEFT JOIN TableA a
ON a.IdUser = b.IdUser
AND a.IdProject = b.IdProject
AND a.IdTool = b.IdTool;

Thank you very much, I had already tried your solution before, but this query gives me only 3 records, not the 6 records that I need, that is, the table that I desire is the one shown in the question. Thank you very much for your help and contribution, I hope you can help me to find the solution.
